# Average Volume of Convex Hull of N points in Unit Hypercube

Tags: convex-geometry

Suppose we randomly pick $N$ points inside the unit hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. What is the expected value of the volume of the convex hull (in any $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$ containing the convex hull)?

For example, if $N=2$, we are asking about the average length of a line segment in a unit square. This can be shown to be $\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+ 5\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{15}\approx 0.521$

Is there a method to compute this expected value in general?

Comment: In addition to Gery Myerson's comments: For $N=2$ you would have two points in $[0,1]$ and not in the unit square. Probably you want $N$ random points in $[0,1]^N$?

Comment: Apologies - edits added for clarity.

Comment: "The average area of a triangle picked at random inside a unit cube is $A=0.15107 \pm 0.00003.$" See [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeTrianglePicking.html).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is answered (in the limit) by

M. E. Dyer, Z. Furedi, and C. McDiarmid. Random volumes in the n-cube. DIMACS Series in Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science 1:33–38, 1990;

and the specific question might well be answered in something that cites this.